# FIWARE IDM installation error

Tags: fiware

I tried to install Fiware IDM in Ubuntu 12.04 from scratch (just only Ubuntu 12.04 was installed, no any more packages). I have followed the guide https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Installation-guide

Installation finished OK, but when I try to start fi-lab home page, http://localhost:8000, I've got the following error:

```
DeprecationWarning: The oslo namespace package is deprecated. Please use oslo_config instead.
DeprecationWarning: The oslo namespace package is deprecated. Please use oslo_config instead.
Validating models...

0 errors found
July 09, 2015 - 13:17:37
Django version 1.6.11, using settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
DEBUG:idm_logger:Creating a new internal keystoneclient connection to https://127.0.0.1:5000/v3.
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
WARNING:py.warnings:InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Recoverable error: SSL exception connecting to https://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/auth/tokens
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in __init__
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/urls.py", line 36, in <module>
    from openstack_dashboard.dashboards.idm_admin.user_accounts \
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/idm_admin/user_accounts/views.py", line 27, in <module>
    from openstack_dashboard.dashboards.idm_admin.user_accounts \
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/idm_admin/user_accounts/forms.py", line 202, in <module>
    class UpdateAccountForm(forms.SelfHandlingForm, UserAccountsLogicMixin, fiware_auth.TemplatedEmailMixin):
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/idm_admin/user_accounts/forms.py", line 209, in UpdateAccountForm
    choices=get_account_choices())
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/idm_admin/user_accounts/forms.py", line 179, in get_account_choices
    use_idm_account=True),
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/fiware_api/keystone.py", line 783, in get_basic_role
    exceptions.handle(request)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/horizon/exceptions.py", line 324, in handle
    messages.error(request, message or log_entry)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/horizon/messages.py", line 83, in error
    fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/horizon/messages.py", line 41, in add_message
    if not horizon_message_already_queued(request, message):
  File "/home/juan/idm/horizon/horizon/messages.py", line 28, in horizon_message_already_queued
    if request.is_ajax():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_ajax'
```

Does anybody know whether we should install additional packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development purposes, change this variable 
from

OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL = "https://%s:5000/v3" % OPENSTACK_HOST to
**OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL = "http://%s:5000/v3" % OPENSTACK_HOST**

inside  idm/horizon/openstack_dashboard/loca/local_settings.py (arround 130th line)