# FIWARE IDM installation error Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: fiware, keystone, openstack-horizon

I'm trying to install Fiware-IDM in Ubuntu 15.04 following the tutorial http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin_guide.html . Everything went ok, but when I try to enter horizon, I'm having the same issue than in [FIWARE IDM installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318859/fiware-idm-installation-error)

Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in the linked thread?

Comment: Yes, I tried the solution of changing the https to http. And the issue persists.